# Script suddenly starts moves system files instead of other directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using the below script to move files from a source directory to a destination1 directory then copy the files to destination2 directory and it works well sometimes but suddenly sometimes it starts moving the whole system files under `/` like `home`, `etc`, `usr`,..... to the destination directory which then the whole machine system is corrupted and I have to do a recovery. So I am not sure why this happens and what can be the reason for this to happen or what triggers it?

```
#!/bin/bash -i
#
alias brc='source ~/.bashrc'
mydir='My-Dir1*'
min_age=5
cdate=$(date +%F)
echo -n "Enter ID: "; read u; echo $u
dstdir1="$(find  /home/myuser/Documents/dstdir1/customers/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*${u}*" -type d)/Transaction_$cdate"
dstdir2="$(find  /home/myuser/Documents/dstdir2/customers/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*${u}*" -type d)/Transaction_$cdate"
mkdir -p $dstdir2
mkdir -p $dstdir1
dir_list=$(find "/home/myuser/Documents/customers/$u/" -type d -iname "$mydir" | grep -iv Recycle.Bin)
echo $dir_list
if [ -z "$dir_list" ]; then
    echo "Error: could not find any directories matching pattern $mydir" >&2
    exit 1
fi
source ~/.bashrc
cwd=$PWD
echo "SELECT THE SOURCE DIRECTORY"

onlyonce=0

select dir in $dir_list; do
    srcdir="/home/myuser/Documents/customers/$u"
    echo "Files will be moved from:"
    echo "$srcdir to"
    echo "$dstdir1 then copied to"
    echo "$dstdir2"
    read -p 'continue (y/n)? ' -r answer
    [ "$answer" = "y" ] || exit 0

    echo "Moving then coping files older than $min_age minutes."
    while :; do
        echo 'setting source file and directory permissions...'
        find "$srcdir" -type d ! -perm 0775 -exec chmod 0775 '{}' \;
        find "$srcdir" -type f ! -perm 0664 -print0 | xargs -0 -r -- chmod 0664
        cd "$srcdir"
        echo 'Moving files...'
        rsync_extra_opts='-ptOW --info=progress2 --no-super --remove-source-files'
        find . -type f -mmin +$min_age -print0 | rsync -0 --files-from=- $rsync_extra_opts ./ "$dstdir1/"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo 'correcting destination directory permissions...'
            find "$dstdir1" -type d ! -perm 0775 -exec chmod -c 0775 '{}' \;
        fi
        cd "$dstdir1"
        echo 'Coping files...'
        rsync_extra_opts='-ptOW --info=progress2 --no-super'
        find . -type f -mmin +$min_age -print0 | rsync -0 --files-from=- $rsync_extra_opts ./ "$dstdir2/"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo 'correcting destination directory permissions...'
            find "$dstdir2" -type d ! -perm 0775 -exec chmod -c 0775 '{}' \;
        fi

        cd "$cwd"
        df -h "$srcdir" "$dstdir1" "$dstdir2"
        echo 'sleeping 5 minutes...'
        sleep 5m
        echo ""
    done
    break
done
cd "$cwd"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that your script is running from `/` and the unprotected `cd "$srcdir"` is failing at some point.

Some suggestions

- Use `printf` statements and/or `set -x` to see what values your variables contain
- Use `rsync --dry-run` and other non-destructive operations while testing
- Protect the `cd "$srcdir"` (`cd "$srcdir" || continue`, or `if cd "$srcdir"; then ...`), or `[[ -d "$srcdir" ]] || continue`)
- Better still, don't change directory anywhere and avoid the `cd` by using full paths in the `rsync`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But what might be causing this to happen? The script is located in a folder in my documents folder. But then I run it using a desktop launcher with the following Exec command  `Exec=x-terminal-emulator -e /home/myuser/Documents/MyApp/myscript.sh`  so I don't know how it runs from `/` ?

Comment: It must be running as root, otherwise it wouldn't be able to move `/usr`, etc. Or you've got a really broken system.

Comment: And how to know if it's running as root or not?

Comment: `id` inside the script

Comment: But there is no `id` in the script. I just wanted to know what could have caused this.

Comment: No there isn't. So put one in there and we what is its running as.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after commenting five times, I've reached the point where I should just post an answer :-)

(Previous comments deleted)

To me it looks like `dstdir1` and `dstdir2` may be empty, so that your `rsync`-command rsyncs to `/`.

To prevent such errors, change the header of your file (trailing space needed after `-`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash - 
set -o nounset   # exit on unset variables.
set -o errexit   # exit on any error.
```

It may be helpful to install `shellcheck` on your box.

I've run it against your script and it complains about unquoted vars on lines 7, 10, 11, 13, 41 and 49.  `onlyonce=0` seems to be unused.

The alias `brc` is unused, and I'd advise against using aliases in shellscripts.  You should use functions instead.

Comment: The [unofficial strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) did wonders for me.